# how to use jquery autocomplete/combobox events handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

trying to bind on focus event of autocomplete/combobox jquery plugin some another action(showing tooltip on wrap element)
jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $( "#municipality_cb" ).combobox({
    focus: function(event, ui) {
         //tipTip(); - tooltip script 
         $("#municipality_wrap").tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10});    
      }        
   });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <!--combobox wrapper div for tooltip -->
  <div id="municipality_wrap" title="Chose municipality: Karposh" style="float: left;">
      <select id="municipality_cb" tabindex="2" data-placeholder="Choose ..." 
        title="test">
            <option value=""></option>
            other options....  
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Tooltip doesnt showing at all. What I do wrong? Help please :)

Jquery autocomplete plugin(look event tab)
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: nope... you could have a quick look at http://jsfiddle.net/wNnTQ/138/ to better understands how is it works...

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. Both the tooltip and autocomplete work in your fiddle.

Comment: acutally the problem is that I cannot handle event on combobox. In my case combobox event should open tooltip, that it doesn't do

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that .combobox doensn't have focus callback as you can see [here](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxapi.aspx).
So you have to use the following code:

```
$("#combobox").focus(function() {
    $("#wrapper").tipsy('show');
}).blur(function() {
    $("#wrapper").tipsy('hide');
});
```

But .combobox changes your dom elements, if you inspect them you will see that it removes your element which id is combobox.
 So the code below won't work.
To solve it you have to change `$("combobox")` to the new dom elements `$("span.ui-combobox input")`.
You can see it working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wNnTQ/141/)**.

Other problem that I see on your code is that you are not using ui autocomplete, look the [rereference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-focus) to know how to use.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. But there is new problem - I have 3 comboboxes form on my site and when I click on any of them the tooltip appear on that combobox :), cs they all have "span.ui-combobox input" element :) any better idea?

Comment: @Alekso put you combobox inside a div and use it as selector. I'll update my code now.

Comment: Ricardo, what do you mean - I don't use ui autocomplete - I use combobox, which based on autocomplete widget http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox , or you mean ui autocomplete like selector?

Comment: @Alekso To use autocomplete you have to use the following $('element').autocomplete();